# Eclipse in Windows using MinGW

Tags: c

I am using Eclipse in Windows 7 using MinGW. But while compiling I am getting errors for some header files included. For example: sys/socket.h. Did I miss out something here.

Comment: Obviously you did, but I guess that your real question is how to resolve the issue. Could you provide more information about the problem?

Comment: For that specific case, `sys/socket.h` is a linux header file: Windows you must use `winsock2.h`

Comment: "Did I miss out something here." Yes... Windows is not Linux. They use completely different sockets.